# ngClass with prefix in class name gives space

Tags: ionic3

I have an HTML element with some class as given below:

```
<div class="table__column--cell"
[ngClass]="{'--toggle': displayToggle == true}">
 ........
</div>
```

When I run the project, I see div with class as "table__column--cell --toggle" instead of "table__column--cell--toggle" which should be without space.

Can someone help with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you want something like

if displayToggle is true then class will be  table__column--cell--toggle or else it will be table__column--cell.

Then u can use conditional operator which is of the form

***condition ? result if condition true : if condition is false***

```
<div [ngClass]="displayToggle == true ? 'table__column--cell--toggle' : 'table__column--cell'">
 ........
</div>
```